# SQL Select IN versus LIKE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, sql-like

Which one is faster in performance?

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4
FROM MyTable
WHERE field5 LIKE '%AL'
```

versus

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4
FROM MyTable
WHERE field5 IN ('AAL', 'IAL')
```

or it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: Did you try it for yourself and see? Usually it won't matter, but I believe LIKE is going to be slower as it's not a simple equivalence test.

Comment: I too vote for "did you try it"?

Answer (score 6):

Your mileage may vary, but the second one should be faster, because it is two index-backed lookups, versus a full index scan. Without an index on field5 it should not matter (full table scan in both cases).

Comment: -1. You are assuming that the fields are indexed, but there is no indication in the question that those fields are; the answer is unfounded.

Comment: @casperOne : He makes no such assumption.  The answer covers both scenarios (with, and with-out the index), by stating that without an index a full table scan is required and so performance would likely be equal.

Comment: @Dems: I can see that, but I think the wording is very misleading, it corrects itself after-the-fact.

Comment: @casperOne : Pedantic deconstruction of linguistics does not pertain to the validity of the answer, especialy in the case that you assert it to be "unfounded".  Not to mention the fact that I dis-agree with your premise and find the linguistic construction of the answer to be legitimate.  I personally don't read half an answer and assume the second half to be irrelevant.

Comment: @Dems: Upvotes and downvotes are not just cast based on how much the answer is a statement of truth, pedantry aside.  Votes can be cast for readability/how well understood it is.  In this case, I think while legitimate, it's readability suffers and will lead others to make assumptions where they should not (remember, SO is part wiki as well, a reference for those who have the same problem and read this later), hence the -1.  It's also moot, I can't change the vote until the answer is changed.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a covering index (or at least an index on field5) then both will require table scans so will be equally poor.

About the queries... The second one is the same as `WHERE field5 = 'AAL' OR field5 = 'IAL'` which is 2 precise values to look for (eg a seek is likely). The LIKE and leading wildcard implies "I don't know how many values to look for" seek will never happen

About indexes... If you do have an index on field5 only, then the second one will probably have 2 key lookups to get the rest of the data. The first will probably ignore this index because it has a *leading wildcard*. So the 2nd is better assuming things behave as I'd expect.

With a covering index, then the 2nd one again bit no key lookup

About search arguments... If you change the IN to variables then the plan will change again. Queries with constants are quicker then queries with variables because with constants the values are known up front.

But, have you tried it...

Comment: +1 "Queries with constants are quicker then queries with variables because with constants the values are known up front." Good point, and one that rarely comes up. Especially if the data is skewed (95% male, 5% female for example), this can make a measurable difference. I'd always go for constants, but only if they come from a very limited set. Otherwise you end up "spamming" the SQL cache. Bind variables would be better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely test on your platform. Some RDBMS are horrible at IN logic, i.e. much slower than you'd expect. Mysql has this issue, you don't specify in your question.

Comment: Really? Most SQLs (please don't call SQL "relational" :) will simply expand the `IN` clause to `(field5 = 'AAL' OR field5 = 'IAL')` and if your SQL product of choice can't optimize that well then it's time to find a new one!

Answer (score 0):

as other stated depends on your choice of RDBMS, if you are using MS SQL, both statements are identical in terms of performance

UPDATE: As per **Martin** comment, the above is true when there are no indexes present for `field5`, which was the original assumption for the question.

Comment: -1 This is not true. It is potentially 2 index seeks on `field5` vs an index scan.

Comment: @Martin, you are ONLY right if there is an index on `field5`, which is not even part of the discussion here, since the assumption is there is no index my answer is 100% correct, try testing it yourself

Comment: Why are you assuming there is no index? There probably should be an index on this column if that is the type of query being run on it.

Comment: I have learn over the years that when things are not stated, they are not existent; it is best not to assume anything. The way I read the question it is clear in my mind there are no indexes involved. Just to be fair though, if there is an index on that column your statement is correct. I still fill the downgrade was undeserved though.

Comment: @K Ivanov - If your answer had stated your assumption I wouldn't have downvoted it. But as it stands it makes a blanket statement which is completely wrong in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is faster than the `LIKE` command...

Comment: Can you explain why IN would be faster than LIKE in this case?